Have any Middleton manuscripts other than A Game at Chess survived?
Thomas Middleton's last play, A Game at Chess, is unique in that more manuscript versions have survived than copies of the original printed edition. Out of the six extant manuscripts, one is entirely by Middleton and one at least in part.
Most English Renaissance plays have survived only in print. For example, we don't have any play manuscripts by Shakespeare, with the possible exception of three pages for Sir Thomas More, which exists in a manuscript in six different hands. (None of those has been attributed to Middleton.)
Have any Middleton manuscripts other than A Game at Chess survived? For clarity's sake, I mean manuscripts by Middleton of one or more of his literary works (including his pamphlets).

The work has been done for us by the Catalogue of English Literary Manuscripts 1450–1700! All we have to do is go to the author page for Thomas Middleton and search for “autograph” and “Middleton’s hand”. There are six matches:

MiT 14 A Game at Chess. Autograph copy, including the Prologue, Epilogue, and Induction. 1624.
MiT 15 A Game at Chess. Principally in a professional secretary hand, with the title-page (f. 1r), folios 21v–2r, 46r–54v (including the Epilogue), and two or three corrections elsewhere in Middleton’s hand. 1624.
MiT 16 A Game at Chess. Copy of an abridged version, xii + 70 quarto leaves. In the hand of Ralph Crane (fl. 1589–1632), poet and scribe, with Middleton’s autograph verse dedication ‘To the worthily accomplished Master William Hammond’ (‘beginning This—which nor stage nor stationer’s stall can show’) subscribed ‘T. M.’ 1624.
MiT 17 A Game at Chess. Copy, 77 quarto pages, in two professional secretary hands, with a title-page in Middleton’s hand ‘A Game at Chesse As it was Acted Nine Dayes together Compos’de by Tho: Middleton’, including the Induction and an Epilogue, in contemporary vellum gilt. 1624.
MiT 18 A Game at Chess. Copy of an early version, in the hand of Ralph Crane (fl. 1589–1632), poet and scribe, on 93 small quarto pages, with one annotation (p. 32) in Middleton’s hand. 1624.
MiT 35 Middleton’s autograph subscription (‘Thomas Midleton: Queen’s’) upon matriculating at The Queen’s College, Oxford, 7 April 1598.

So the only literary manuscripts in Middleton’s own hand that have survived are copies of A Game at Chess.
